# Build a strend function with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

As the title says,I must build a strend function with pointers.The function will check if the second string appears at the end of the first string and return 1 if it does or 0 if it doesnt.Here is my code,it is not compiling and its giving an non lvalue in assigment error.Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int strend (char *s1,char *s2);
int main()
{
    char string1[MAX]="Check Mate";
    char string2[MAX]="Mate";
    printf("The Result is :\n");
    printf("%d",strend(string1,string2));
    return 0;
}
int strend (char *s1,char *s2)
{
    for(;*s1!='\0';s1++)
                        { for(;*s2!='\0' && *s1!='\0' && *s1==*s2;s1++,s2++)
                                       ;
                                       }
    if(*s1='\0' && *s2='\0')
                return 1;
    else 
                return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error shown by the compiler indicates that you are trying to assign to something which is not an `LVALUE`. In simple terms `LVALUE` refers to the terms which can appear on the left hand side of an assignment, (in reality it is much more complex than that ;) )

You need to use `==` for the equality comparison instead of `=`

```
if (*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0')
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;
```

Also note that the compiler was showing the error at `*s2 = '\0'` and was not complaining about the first assignment `*s1 = '\0'` (even though it is logically incorrect to your program requirement).

In other words the compiler would not have shown the LVALUE error with just this statement:

```
if (*s1 = '\0')
```

Only when you had an `&& *s2 = '\0'`, it showed the error.

And as teppic pointed out in the comments below, it is because of the expression being evaluated equivalent to `if(*s1 = ('\0' && *s2) = '\0')`
 (because of operator precedence) which made the compiler show the LVALUE error, since you cannot have `0 = 0` in an expression.

Comment: Lol,thanks mate...I would have never thought about that particular mistake :P,I even have another mistake which put an output of 1 even when the second string was found on the first one (even if it wasnt in the end).

Comment: Although the code was incorrect, the error was generated because it was trying to assign 0 to `('\0' && *s2)`, i.e. `0 = 0;`

Comment: @teppic - That is not correct, there was no such assignment in the code. For example try this simple case, and you would see what I'm saying: `int a, b; if (a == 1 && b = 2)` would give you an error, but if you only had `if (b = 2)`, the compiler will not show an error.

Comment: @Tuxdude There was, it's just operator precedence. Put parentheses around the original expressions and it'll compile fine.

Comment: @teppic - have updated the answer, I believe you meant assigning '\0' to `(0 && *s2)` is that correct ? That was why I got misled :)

Comment: @Tuxdude - yep that's right. `\0` equals 0 of course, so the original  statement eventually breaks down to `if (*s1 = 0 = 0)`, and it's the `0 = 0` causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `*s2!='\0'` to the first For condition.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this snippet .

```
char str1[50]="Check Mate";
char str2[50]="Mate";
int flag,i,l1,l2;

l1=strlen(str1);
l2=strlen(str2);
/*
 * Place a pointer to the end of strings 1 and strings 2 . 
 */
char *ptrend1 = (str1+l1-1);
char *ptrend2 = (str2+l2-1);


flag = 1; 
for(i=l2;i>0;i--)
{
    /*
     * Keep traversing such that in case the last charachters of the stings
     * dont match break out . 
     */
    if(*ptrend2 != *ptrend1){
        flag = 0 ;
        break;
    }
    /*
     * Decrement both the end pointers 
     */
    ptrend1--;
    ptrend2--;
}
if(flag)
    printf("String 2 is contained at the end of string 1");
else 
    printf("String 2 is NOT contained at the end of string 1");
return 0;
```